Marking objects in the image and labelling them
I have a 3d tikz plot with me.I am totally clueless on making boxes,and putting arrows to mark length of a  specific area in the  tikz file.
I also want to mark certain region with dashed rectangle and label it as something
Can you give me an idea on how to do these
The code for this is as follows
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
         grid,
         enlargelimits = false,
         xmin = -18.549999,
         xmax = 65.450005,
         ymin = -16.000000,
         ymax = 47.750000,
         zmin = -4.000000,
         zmax = 4.100000,
         xlabel = {x in [m]},
         ylabel = {y in [m]},
         zlabel = {z in [m]},
         colorbar,
         colormap name=parula,
         colorbar style = {%,
             ylabel = {height},
         },
         point meta min = -1.000000,
         point meta max = 4.000000,
     ]

         \addplot3 graphics[
             points={% important
                 (-18.549999,-16.000000,-4.000000) => (149.000000,87.000000)
                 (-18.549999,47.750000,4.100000) => (47.000000,172.000000)
                 (65.450005,-16.000000,4.100000) => (323.000000,173.000000)
                 (65.450005,47.750000,-4.000000) => (221.000000,220.000000)
         }]{gfx/MaptypeAmplitudeAzimuth1Elevation1Frame300to3200Resolution15cmAllSensorsThreshold80.png};

     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Shubham

Welcome. // Like many, many other new users you didn't provide all code lines to compile your example. Usually this leads to a very low response rate. // As pgfplots is based on Tikz, you can always "draw" other objects on top, like \node[draw, rounded corners, red] at (.5,.5){}; . See the pgfmanual for details on the right coordinates to chose. You can do it in absolute coordinates, like mine (not checked), and, if you are lucky, also here via àxis cs:` .
